# retain all entered values after redirect to the same page

Tags: asp.net

I have registration page which contains many text boxes, check box and date picker etc., When tick one of the check box it will redirect to the sub- registration page. After click on button from the sub-registration page, it should redirect to the registration page and I would like to retain all the values which I have entered already. If I use session I have to write lots lines of code. Is there any other way to do?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use session if the user is going to be navigated away from the page, there is no way around that.

It might be possible not to redirect the user, and have the sub-registration elements on the same page, hidden and shown as needed using JavaScript.

If you have to navigate away, then you have to use session. In this case, to reduce the amount of code required, you could develop a custom control that uses a session-backed-property for it's values (Here is an example: https://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/code/431276/session-backed-properties)

You can then re-use this custom control to replace all of your textboxes (You might need a custom control for each type that you use, textbox, dropdown etc.)

Here is a sample implementation of a user control with a session backed value:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SessionTextBox.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebForms_Tests.UserControls.SessionTextBox" %>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="theTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```

The Code Behind:

```
public partial class SessionTextBox : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected string SessionValue
    {
        get
        {
            object temp = Session["sessionBackedControlValue:" + this.UniqueID];
            return temp == null ? string.Empty : temp as string;
        }
        set
        {
            Session["sessionBackedControlValue:" + this.UniqueID] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SessionValue = theTextBox.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            theTextBox.Text = SessionValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always just have everything on 1 page in separate divs. Once first one posts back hide it and show other, then switch them again on second postback.

Comment: I have developed a running sample using the code in the answer above, could you mark the answer as accepted? PM me if you would like me to send you the full source code.